# If $a<b-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, then $a<0$

Tags: real-analysis, logic, solution-verification

Decide whether the statement is true or false
If $a<b-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, then $a<0$?

Here my attempt,

**attempt**

If $a<b-\epsilon$, using additive property $\epsilon<b-a$

By $\epsilon > 0$ and $\epsilon<b-a$,  $0<\epsilon<b-a$

which implies $\epsilon$ is fixed value but given for all for all $\epsilon>0$

thus according to the $P\Rightarrow Q$ if p is false statement is true thus this statement is true

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: What is $b$ here?

Comment: This is seen to be true if we take $\epsilon \ge b$. However this $a$ will not exist, so the statement is weird (or vacuously true)

Comment: Are you sure you copied the problem down right? Since it seems like $a$ would have to be negative infinity.

Comment: @player3236 is this correct?

Comment: @IntegrateThis yes i' m sure

Comment: @IntegrateThis if it happens also this is false?

Comment: Well using order relations with negative infinity I'm not so sure tbh. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Choosing an explicit $\epsilon$ would be clearer (and shorter). However I would say there is nothing fundamentally wrong with your proof.

Comment: @player3236 Thank you I got it